# hd0 not found, ubuntu installed

Tags: boot, system-installation, grubrescue

I tried to dual boot Win7/Ubuntu, but the installer wouldn't recognize the free space on my hard drive, so I followed the advice of erasing RAID metadata with the command `dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` and that let me install Ubuntu, but when I rebooted my computer I was greeted with grub rescue.

Then, I tried to re-install Ubuntu, this time erasing the disk and completely disregarding Windows. I was hoping a fresh install would fix grub (as I don't care about Win), but I still get either grub rescue prompt, or (hd0) not found. The hard drive shows in fdisk and gparted.

I'm on an HP with triple core 2.6 GHz, 8 Gb ram. 


[image]


[image]

Comment: Are you sure you installed GRUB on right hard drive?

Comment: There is only one hard drive in the system. All externals have been removed. The screen shots are from my live session of Puppy Linux (sdb).

Answer (score 0):

I changed my BIOS setting from RAID/AHCI to Native IDE and it booted up directly. From what I read, there's supposed to be a performance penalty using IDE, but I haven't used it long enough to say for myself.